# OpenGL fullscreen rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, fullscreen, antialiasing

I'm currently coding a game in openGL and I've got to a stage where I'm in first person mode controlling the "camera" with W & S, and rotating with the mouse.

For some reason, when I'm in windowed mode, the speeds at which I move and rotate seems MUCH faster than the speeds I get when In fullscreen, but that's not my main issue. **(*1)**

As a result of the above, I decided to restrict the game to fullscreen.

My level is a cube where each side is a different RGB colour and when I move my mouse very quickly, the corners of the level turn very blocky until I slow down. **(*2)**

Anyone got any idea what's going on for either the questions (*1, *2).

I tried to screenshot it for you guys, but it looks normal in the screenshot.

Comment: what kind of frame rate are you getting in fullscreen vs windowed?

Comment: Are you using GLUT or an OS API like win32?

Comment: Erm, I don't know what frame rate I'm getting it, any way to show it without coding it? :P And yes, I use the GLUT library.

Comment: If it is getting blocky when you turn really fast it could be due to vsync... as for the camera moving too fast: everything in a game must rely on the time between frames. So your camera rotation code should be like : `camera.rotate(rotx * timeSinceLastFrame, roty * timeSinceLastFrame)`. This keeps everything at a constant speed.

Comment: Ah ok :) Regarding timeSinceLastFrame, are there any good clean methods of doing such things instead of math calculations, maybe a GLUT timer or something? This is all very new to me :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measure your frame times with `glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)`:

```
void displayCallback()
{
    int start = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    drawFrame();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    int end = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    cout << "Frame time: " << (end-start) << "ms" << endl;
}
```

If they're around 16-17ms you most likely have some vsync.  Managing vsync is system-dependent, both in access method and reliability :(

Your best bet is [frame-rate independence](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/), so you do the Right Thing no matter how fast/slow you're running.